# Orthogonal and Combinatorial testing techniques

Tags: testing, black-box-testing, manual-testing

What is Orthogonal testing technique?
What is Combinatorial testing technique?
What is the difference between them?
I went through wikipedia and other articles and books but still i am unable to understand them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Orthogonal testing-  Orthogonal array testing is a black box testing technique.
It is used when number of inputs to the application under test is small but too complex for an exhaustive testing. It is very effective in finding errors.

All Pair Testing- It is type of testing Technique to test all the pairs using combinatorial method.

1- Pairwise testing is more efficient and effective than orthogonal arrays for software testing.

2- Orthogonal testing is more effective for manufacturing, and agriculture, and advertising.

3- Pairwise testing strategy better than an orthogonal array strategy.

4- Both Type of  testing Technique reduce the  number of Test cases.

5- All Pair testing almost  requires fewer test cases than orthogonal testing, sometimes both have same number of test cases.

Both type of testing Strategy have almost same features but at the same time the use(which testing Strategy to choose) depends on the requirement.

Please refer this pdf for more details-

```
http://www.51testing.com/ddimg/uploadsoft/20090113/OATSEN.pdf
```

Tutorial for Pairwise Testing with examples-

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/software_testing_dictionary/all_pairs_testing.htm

Answer (score 0):

Refer the below link .I think it is useful to you.

http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/combinational-test-technique/

Answer (score 0):

Orthogonal Array can be of any strength.

when its combination of any 2 Variables its called all pairs
it can be combination of any 3, 4, 5...n variables based on the business need. All pairs is just one of the subclasses of orthogonal testing. Hope this helps